# jade passed variable remain undefined

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a strange problem which is i could not pass varible in jade.actually the passed variable will show as 'undefined' at the client side while i defined it when i render the response!

here is the nodejs code:

```
//username will work but name will be undefined
res.render('new-sensor-settings', { username: req.session.username, name:'myname'})
```

here is how i used it in my jade file:

```
label(for='s_name') Name
input#s_name.span10(type='text', value='#{name}' )
```

i updated the jade to the latest with 'npm update jade' command.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use `#{}` interpolation when you want to insert a variable into the element's text. Use the variable directly when you are putting it in an attribute.

```
label(for='s_name') Name
input#s_name.span10(type='text', value=name)
label#demo Yo what's up mister #{name}
```

Comment: I don't know why but when i use this way the value which name should be replaced into it will be empty instead of being 'undefined'. any idea?

Comment: with `res.render('new-sensor-settings', { username: req.session.username, name:'myname'})` and `input#s_name.span10(type='text', value=name)` you should definitely see `value="myname"` in the rendered html output. double check everything - maybe you defined a new variable `name` above these lines in your jade code, or you are actually calling `render` differently? my last guess is that maybe jade is overwriting `name` internally?

Comment: This ended up being a combination of a couple different issues, see the followup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401773/jade-server-side-passed-variable-is-empty-at-browser/19404753#19404753