# jade server side passed variable is empty at browser

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a strange problem which is the passed variable to the jade is empty at the browser,
it seems the passed variable is null but it isn't

the nodejs code(the whole route code):

```
    exports.sensorsettings = function(req, res){
    if (!req.session.username) {
        // if false render
        res.render('login', { logo: 'img/owl.png', id: 'home', brand: brand })
    } else {
        if(!req.query.sid) (res.redirect('/dashboard'));
        // get sid information from database
            db.collection('sensors').findOne({sid:req.query.sid}, function(err, result) {
                console.log('this is result:' + result);
                if (result) {
                    console.log('this is result:' + result.name);
                    result= JSON.stringify(result);
                    res.render('new-sensor-settings', { username: req.session.username, name:result.name,
                        ipaddress: result.ipaddress, desc: result.desc, snmpcom: result.snmpcom, snmpver: result.snmpver,
                        snmpport: result.snmpport, snmpifindex: result.snmpifindex, ncusername: result.ncusername,
                        ncport: result.ncport})
                };
                if (!result) res.redirect('/errors?err=db');
            });
        // if true redirect
        res.render('new-sensor-settings', { username: req.session.username, id: 'home', brand: brand })

    }
};
```

jade file(the whole form):

```
form.form-horizontal
                    .tab-content(style='padding: 0;')
                        #account-details.tab-pane
                            .row-fluid
                                .span6
                                    .control-group
                                        label.control-label Community
                                        .controls
                                            input#s_snmpcom.span10(type='text', value=snmpcom)
                                            span.btn-action.single.glyphicons.circle_question_mark(style='margin: 0;', data-toggle='tooltip', data-placement='top', data-original-title='Specify your device Public Community name (For SNMP version 2c)')
                                                i
                                    .control-group
                                        label.control-label Port Number
                                        .controls
                                            input#s_snmpport.input-mini(type='text', value=snmpport)
                                            span.btn-action.single.glyphicons.circle_question_mark(style='margin: 0;', data-toggle='tooltip', data-placement='top', data-original-title='Specify your device SNMP port number, Default number is 161 ')
                                                i
                                .span6
                                    .control-group
                                        label.control-label Version
                                        .controls
                                            select#s_snmpver.selectpicker.span6(data-style='btn-default', style='display: none;')
                                                option 1
                                                option 2c
                                                option 3
                                    .control-group
                                        label.control-label IfIndex
                                        .controls
                                            input#s_snmpif.input-mini(type='text', value=snmpifindex)
                                            span.btn-action.single.glyphicons.circle_question_mark(style='margin: 0;', data-toggle='tooltip', data-placement='top', data-original-title='Specify your SNMP interface index number.it could be found at interface details of your device')
                                                i
                            hr.separator.bottom
                            .row-fluid
                                .span6
                                    .control-group
                                        label.control-label Username
                                        .controls
                                            input#s_ncuser.span10(type='text', value=ncusername)
                                            span.btn-action.single.glyphicons.circle_question_mark(style='margin: 0;', data-toggle='tooltip', data-placement='top', data-original-title='Specify your device Netconf username, it could be on of defined username on your device with readonly access.')
                                                i
                                    .control-group
                                        label.control-label Port Number
                                        .controls
                                            input#s_ncport.input-mini(type='text', value=ncport)
                                            span.btn-action.single.glyphicons.circle_question_mark(style='margin: 0;', data-toggle='tooltip', data-placement='top', data-original-title='Specify your device ssh port number, Default number is 22 ')
                                                i
                                .span6
                                    .control-group
                                        label.control-label password
                                        .controls
                                            input#s_ncpass.span10(type='password', value='')
                                            span.btn-action.single.glyphicons.circle_question_mark(style='margin: 0;', data-toggle='tooltip', data-placement='top', data-original-title='Enter the password of Netconf username')
                                                i
                            .form-actions(style='margin: 0;')
                                button.btn.btn-icon.btn-primary.glyphicons.circle_ok.pull-right(type='submit')
                                    i
                                    | Save changes
                                button.btn.btn-icon.btn-default.glyphicons.circle_remove.pull-right(type='button')
                                    i
                                    | Cancel
                        #account-settings.tab-pane.active
                            .row-fluid
                                .span3
                                    strong Sensor General Settings
                                    p.muted Configure Sensor basic settings here,all fields are required.
                                .span9
                                    label(for='s_name') Name
                                    input#s_name.span10(type='text', value=name)
                                    span.btn-action.single.glyphicons.circle_question_mark(style='margin: 0;', data-toggle='tooltip', data-placement='top', data-original-title='Give your sensor a name so you could call it!')
                                        i
                                    .separator
                                    label(for='s_ip') IP Address
                                    input#s_ip.span10(type='text', value=ipaddress , placeholder=''  )
                                    span.btn-action.single.glyphicons.circle_question_mark(style='margin: 0;', data-toggle='tooltip', data-placement='top', data-original-title='Enter sensor IP address here')
                                        i
                                    .separator
                                    label(for='s_offline') Sensor Offline
                                    input#inputPasswordNew.span12(type='text', value='', placeholder='if your sensor is down for maintenance, change its status to offline')
                                    .separator
                                    label(for='s_description') Description
                                    input#s_description.span12(type='text', value=desc)
                                    .separator
                            .form-actions(style='margin: 0; padding-right: 0;')
                                button.btn.btn-icon.btn-primary.glyphicons.circle_ok.pull-right(type='submit')
                                    i
                                    | Save changes
```

note: everything except the username variable will not work. i tried to assign a static value for those variables (for example name:'test') but it won't work neither.

Comment: Should work (and in fact, it does for me). Is the value attribute actually empty, or does it just not show in the input field?

Comment: actually the attribute is not shown!, in html i could not find the value field of s_name when i use value=sname in my jade file. it other words the input field has no value attribute.

Comment: Very strange! Does this minimal example work? ([gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/b5628ceb425f742b8a6e)) (`jade@0.35.0`, `express@3.4.1`)

Comment: the simple version works, very strange problem :(

Comment: Perhaps post some more code?

Comment: I'm counting three `res.render` calls, are you sure you're getting the results from the correct one? Also, you need to make sure that you call `res.render()` or `res.redirect()` just once during the entire request (it looks like the last `res.render()` will always be called, even if the code above it generates a redirect or render)

Comment: as @robertklep points out, the render call on the line following `// if true redirect` will be called immediately after firing `db.collection('sensors').findOne(...`. So by the time the callback of `findOne` executes, including the inner `res.render` statement, a response has already been sent by the outer `res.render`

Comment: mmm, i removed the last res.render call and now the only render of my page contain those variables but still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish here but here is a starting
point. The main change I made was removing the two lines

```
// if true redirect
res.render('new-sensor-settings', { username: req.session.username, id: 'home', brand: brand })
```

because those were being executed before the callback of
`db.collection.findOne`, and thus prevented a response from being sent when the
inner `res.render` was called. I am just guessing that these lines are
extraneous, perhaps a leftover from a previous iteration of the function. If
they are not accidental, please provide more information about what the function
should do.

Other minor changes I made:

Reindented to 2 spaces.

I added curly brackets around the `if(!req.query.sid)` statement. (it's fine to
have one-line `if` statements without the curly brackets, but it's less
maintainable, so my personal preference is to always add them.)

I added `return` in front of the statements that send a response. Since the
`res.redirect` and `res.render` statements are all placed at the end of their
respective `if` blocks, there is no longer any chance of two of them executing.
So the `return`s here aren't strictly really necessary - it's just my personal
preference to use them, making it explicit that now that the response has been
sent, no further code should be executed in this route.

I moved `if(!result)` into an else block attached to the previous `if(result)`

```
exports.sensorsettings = function(req, res){
  if (!req.session.username) {
    // if false render
    return res.render('login', { logo: 'img/owl.png', id: 'home', brand: brand })
  } else {
    if(!req.query.sid){ (return res.redirect('/dashboard')); }
    // get sid information from database
    db.collection('sensors').findOne({sid:req.query.sid}, function(err, result) {
      console.log('this is result:' + result);
      if (result) {
        console.log('this is result:' + result.name);
        // Problem here too:
        result= JSON.stringify(result);
        // result is now a string, trying to access properties will be undefined
        return res.render('new-sensor-settings', { username: req.session.username, name:result.name,
          ipaddress: result.ipaddress, desc: result.desc, snmpcom: result.snmpcom, snmpver: result.snmpver,
          snmpport: result.snmpport, snmpifindex: result.snmpifindex, ncusername: result.ncusername,
          ncport: result.ncport})
      } else {
        return res.redirect('/errors?err=db');
      };
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks for your help and for what @robertklep said. to prevent any typo errors, i copied your code completely to fix the issued you mentioned but still it doesn't work :(

Comment: please elaborate. do you see any errors in the node console? does the `new-sensor-settings` template render? does `this is result` get logged to console, and is it what you are expecting?

Comment: Oh I just noticed that you are calling `result=JSON.stringify(result);` and then trying to access properties of the string. that won't work. comment out the `result=JSON.stringify(result);` line so you are accessing the properties of the result object itself (e.g. with `result.desc`). if `result` is already a JSON string, you want to turn it into an object with `result = JSON.parse(result)`

Comment: thanks! before i read your last comment i removed the JSON.stringify line without any reason and saw it worked! and now i see you have a reason for that!. i will appreciate if you could provide more information about that JSON.strigify line coz i don't fully understand the reason of this issue. thanks again for your help

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is used to turn an object into a JSON-encoded string suitable for embedding in HTML or sending it across the wire some other way. `JSON.parse` is the inverse version that turns a JSON-encoded string back into an object. So the line `result=JSON.stringify(result);` takes the object `result` and turns it into a string, and then sets the variable `result` to be that string, no longer the object. You can't use dot or bracket notation to access properties of a stringified object, so e.g. `result.ipaddress` tried to access the `.ipaddress` property of a string, which is `undefined`.

Answer (score -2):

try this notation `#{ipaddress}`, works for me every time

Comment: doesn't work when you are trying to set a `value` attribute to a jade local variable

Comment: didnt know that, but from what I see - thats not what topic starter wants, it should work for his case, am I wrong?

Comment: OP's problem is that the template never sees the local variables because the wrong render statement is called

Comment: Ok, my fault, sorry for misunderstanding.